# Can you run Tabnine and Github Copilot together?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Is it possible to run Tabnine and Github Copilot together? Can one override the other? Is this even advised? If they both use greyed out code completion suggestions, how would you be able to tell which one is presenting the suggested code?  I'm using Intellij.

Comment: yes, it´s possible. just use tabnine only for popup completions (CTRL+Space) and copilot for inline-suggestions, while you are typing. so you get the best of both worlds. after testing both for a long time, I see copilot as the clear winner here.

Comment: Well Copilot at least works... all tabnine shows on my status bar is a "tabnine starter" Icon, and a message saying "something went wrong" after reinstalling it several times. Copilot worked on the first try.